# visual odometry (rpg_svo vs viso2)

Tags: slam, navigation, visual-odometry, viso2-ros, viso2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone have an experience between these two visual odometry packages?
(e.g. for a wide-angle camera attached to an end of robot arm)
The paper also does not seem talk about it.

http://wiki.ros.org/viso2?distro=indigo

https://github.com/uzh-rpg/rpg_svo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234096/visual-odometry-(rpg_svo-vs-viso2)/) by [jys](https://answers.ros.org/users/3404/jys/) on ROS Answers with karma: 212 on 2016-05-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Behsad Ghanei](https://answers.ros.org/users/26974/behsad-ghanei/) on 2016-05-25**:
Hi,

if you have chosen viso2_ros for visual odometry, could you offer me which guides/tutorials/readmes you used to set it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

Before comparison, I must mention that if you want to use one single camera, your localization would be up to a scale. Even the method that monocular viso2 uses for scale estimation holds for ground vehicles and tries to estimate ground plane. I don't think an arm robot convey such a condition!

BUT regardless of scale,

rpg_svo is much more newer and efficient than viso2. It also benefits from local bundle adjustment which makes it more accurate. The only limitation is that rpg_svo was designed for downward looking cameras. Fortunately, they have recently released SVO 2.0 that handles forward looking as well as stereo and multi-camera systems. But bear in mind that SVO is a direct method for visual odometry. All direct methods, like LSD SLAM and DSO, need global shutter cameras. Rolling shutters induce huge geometric distortions which can deteriorate accuracy. If you use a rolling shutter camera, increase the frame rate to reduce this effect.

---

Originally posted by [ZanaZak](https://answers.ros.org/users/30251/zanazak/) with karma: 58 on 2018-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2018-03-10**:
Thanks for the insight -- very helpful. Do you have a recommendation for a stereo odometry package that tracks features?